# How can I load an UIImage into a SwiftUI Image asynchronously?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI there are some `.init` methods to create an Image but none of them admits a block or any other way to load an UIImage from network/cache...

I am using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to load images from network and cache inside a list row, but the way to draw the image in the view is to re-render it again, which I would prefer to not do. Also, I am creating a fake image(only coloured) as placeholder while the image gets fetched.
Another way would be to wrap all inside a custom view and only re-render the wrapper. But I haven't tried yet.

This sample is working right now.
Any idea to improve the current one will be great

Some view using the loader

```swift
struct SampleView : View {

    @ObjectBinding let imageLoader: ImageLoader

    init(imageLoader: ImageLoader) {
        self.imageLoader = imageLoader
    }

    var body: some View {
       Image(uiImage: imageLoader.image(for: "https://url-for-image"))
          .frame(width: 128, height: 128)
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
    }

}
```

```swift
import UIKit.UIImage
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import class Kingfisher.ImageDownloader
import struct Kingfisher.DownloadTask
import class Kingfisher.ImageCache
import class Kingfisher.KingfisherManager

class ImageLoader: BindableObject {

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<ImageLoader, Never>()
    private let downloader: ImageDownloader
    private let cache: ImageCache
    private var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            dispatchqueue.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.didChange.send(self)
            }
        }
    }
    private var task: DownloadTask?
    private let dispatchqueue: DispatchQueue

    init(downloader: ImageDownloader = KingfisherManager.shared.downloader,
         cache: ImageCache = KingfisherManager.shared.cache,
         dispatchqueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.downloader = downloader
        self.cache = cache
        self.dispatchqueue = dispatchqueue
    }

    deinit {
        task?.cancel()
    }

    func image(for url: URL?) -> UIImage {
        guard let targetUrl = url else {
            return UIImage.from(color: .gray)
        }
        guard let image = image else {
            load(url: targetUrl)
            return UIImage.from(color: .gray)
        }
        return image
    }

    private func load(url: URL) {
        let key = url.absoluteString
        if cache.isCached(forKey: key) {
            cache.retrieveImage(forKey: key) {  [weak self] (result) in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    self.image = value.image
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        } else {
            downloader.downloadImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) {  [weak self] (result) in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let value):
                    self.cache.storeToDisk(value.originalData, forKey: url.absoluteString)
                    self.image = value.image
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In this case you need to use `Image(uiImage: imageLoader.image` to set an image to view. And start image downloading on init or before presenting the Image view struct

Comment: [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/SwiftUI-Support) now supports swiftUI

Answer (score 17):

### SwiftUI 3

Starting from iOS 15 we can now use [`AsyncImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage?changes=latest_minor):

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/icon.png")) { image in
    image.resizable()
} placeholder: {
    ProgressView()
}
.frame(width: 50, height: 50)
```

---

### SwiftUI 2

Here is a native SwiftUI solution that supports **caching** and multiple loading states:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct NetworkImage: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    let url: URL?

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let data = viewModel.imageData, let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            } else if viewModel.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.loadImage(from: url)
        }
    }
}
```

```
extension NetworkImage {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var imageData: Data?
        @Published var isLoading = false

        private static let cache = NSCache<NSURL, NSData>()

        private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

        func loadImage(from url: URL?) {
            isLoading = true
            guard let url = url else {
                isLoading = false
                return
            }
            if let data = Self.cache.object(forKey: url as NSURL) {
                imageData = data as Data
                isLoading = false
                return
            }
            URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .map { $0.data }
                .replaceError(with: nil)
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink { [weak self] in
                    if let data = $0 {
                        Self.cache.setObject(data as NSData, forKey: url as NSURL)
                        self?.imageData = data
                    }
                    self?.isLoading = false
                }
                .store(in: &cancellables)
        }
    }
}
```

(The above code doesn't use any third-party libraries, so it's easy to change the `NetworkImage` in any way.)

---

**Demo**

[image]

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showImage = false

    var body: some View {
        if showImage {
            NetworkImage(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png"))
                .frame(maxHeight: 150)
                .padding()
        } else {
            Button("Load") {
                showImage = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I used an exceptionally large Stack Overflow logo to show the loading state.)

Answer (score 10):

Pass your Model to ImageRow struct which contains url.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView : View {
    var listData: Post
    var body: some View {
        List(model.post) { post in
            ImageRow(model: post) // Get image
        }
    }
}

/********************************************************************/
// Download Image

struct ImageRow: View {
    let model: Post
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            ImageViewContainer(imageUrl: model.avatar_url)
        }
    }
}

struct ImageViewContainer: View {
    @ObjectBinding var remoteImageURL: RemoteImageURL

    init(imageUrl: String) {
        remoteImageURL = RemoteImageURL(imageURL: imageUrl)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: remoteImageURL.data) ?? UIImage())
            .resizable()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3.0))
            .frame(width: 70.0, height: 70.0)
    }
}

class RemoteImageURL: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Data, Never>()
    var data = Data() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(data)
        }
    }
    init(imageURL: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: imageURL) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.data = data }

            }.resume()
    }
}
/********************************************************************/
```

Comment: This does not work in Xcode 11 beta 7 and GM  replaced BindableObject with ObservableObject and ObjectBinding with ObservedObject, but it does not work to load the remote image. Any suggestions

Comment: Update: Work with that change --> `@Published var data = Data()`

Answer (score 5):

A simpler and cleaner way to load an image in SwiftUI is to use the renowned Kingfisher library.

1. Add `Kingfisher` via Swift Package Manager

> Select File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency. Enter
>   https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.git
>
> in the "Choose Package
>   Repository" dialog. In the next page, specify the version resolving
>   rule as "Up to Next Major" with "5.8.0" as its earliest version.
>
> After
>   Xcode checking out the source and resolving the version, you can
>   choose the "KingfisherSwiftUI" library and add it to your app target.

2. `import KingfisherSwiftUI`
3. `KFImage(myUrl)`

Done! It's that easy

Comment: the version i am using today (10-10-2021) appears to have a dependency on ProgressView (part of preview).  I can comment it out and ignore the problem, but I prefer to include.  Any idea where ProgressView dependency comes from?

Answer (score 3):

I would just use the `onAppear` callback

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import UIKit
    struct ImagePreviewModel {
        var urlString : String
        var width : CGFloat = 100.0
        var height : CGFloat = 100.0
    }

    struct ImagePreview: View {
        let viewModel: ImagePreviewModel
        @State var initialImage = UIImage()
        var body: some View {
            Image(uiImage: initialImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: self.width, height: self.height)
                .onAppear {
                    guard let url = URL(string: self.viewModel.urlString) else { return }
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                        guard let data = data else { return }
                        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }

                        RunLoop.main.perform {
                            self.initialImage = image
                        }

                    }.resume()
                }
        }
        var width: CGFloat { return max(viewModel.width, 100.0) }
        var height: CGFloat { return max(viewModel.height, 100.0) }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the `imageLoader` as [`@ObjectBinding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/objectbinding):

```
@ObjectBinding private var imageLoader: ImageLoader
```

---

It would make more sense to init the view with the url for the image :

```
struct SampleView : View {

    var imageUrl: URL

    private var image: UIImage {
        imageLoader.image(for: imageUrl)
    }

    @ObjectBinding private var imageLoader: ImageLoader

    init(url: URL) {
        self.imageUrl = url
        self.imageLoader = ImageLoader()
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
    }
}
```

For example :

```
//Create a SampleView with an initial photo
var s = SampleView(url: URL(string: "https://placebear.com/200/300")!)
//You could then update the photo by changing the imageUrl
s.imageUrl = URL(string: "https://placebear.com/200/280")!
```

Comment: The code I left is a sample, I forgot to add it. Thanks for pointing it @ielyamani

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
struct UrlImageView: View {
@ObservedObject var urlImageModel: UrlImageModel

init(urlString: String?) {
    urlImageModel = UrlImageModel(urlString: urlString)
}

var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: urlImageModel.image ?? UrlImageView.defaultImage!)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
}

static var defaultImage = UIImage(systemName: "photo")
}

class UrlImageModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var image: UIImage?
var urlString: String?

init(urlString: String?) {
    self.urlString = urlString
    loadImage()
}

func loadImage() {
    loadImageFromUrl()
}

func loadImageFromUrl() {
    guard let urlString = urlString else {
        return
    }
    
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: 
getImageFromResponse(data:response:error:))
    task.resume()
}


func getImageFromResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) 
{
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("No data found")
        return
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            return
        }
        self.image = loadedImage
    }
}
}
```

And using like this:

```
UrlImageView(urlString: "https://developer.apple.com/assets/elements/icons/swiftui/swiftui-96x96_2x.png").frame(width:100, height:100)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the release of iOS 15 and macOS 12 in 2021, SwiftUI provides native `AsyncImage` view that enables loading images asynchronously. Bear in mind that you'll still have to fall back to a custom implementation for earlier OS versions.

```swift
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/tile.png"))
```

The API itself also provides various ways to customise the image or provide a placeholder, for example:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/tile.png")) { image in
    image.resizable(resizingMode: .tile)
} placeholder: {
    Color.green
}
```

More in the [Apple Developer Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage?changes=latest_minor)