# Subclass-like behaviour for wrapped SwiftUI views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'll try to explain what I'm looking for with an example.

---

Let's say I have implemented a loading image concept, which looks like this:

```swift
struct AsyncImage: View {
    @ObservedObject private var imageDownloader: ImageDownloader

    init(url: URL) {
        imageDownloader = ImageDownloader(url: url)
    }

    var body: Image {
        Image(uiImage: imageDownloader.image)
    }
}

class ImageDownloader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage

    init(url: URL) { /* ... */ }
    // implementation details unimportant
}
```

The above implementation allows easy re-usage through the app:

```swift
struct UserDetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: userProfileUrl).resizable().aspectRatio(16.0 / 9.0, contentMode: .fit)
            Text(user.name)
        }
    }
}
```

However the above code doesn't compile, as `resizable()` is only part of `Image`. How can I make this functionality available, in a clean manner?

Adding an `isResizable` flag to the struct will solve the problem, however the solution is neither scalable nor forward compatible.

Using a `Publisher` and a `ViewModifier` might work, however I can't wrap my head around the combination of these concepts.

---

Any suggestions of tackling this? Or am I trying to solve this the wrong way?

Comment: Why not just extend or subclass UIImageView?

Comment: @Roope that won’t help me much in the context of SwiftUI

Comment: Oh true, my bad. Did you see this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545572/how-can-i-load-an-uiimage-into-a-swiftui-image-asynchronously

Comment: @Roope yes, I stumbled upon that SO post, my problem is not necessarily the async image loading, but the pattern to use for exposing functionalities of the embedded view. I'll update the question to better reflect this.

Comment: why don't you use already made working code? https://github.com/cmtrounce/SwURL

Comment: @Chris repo looks interesting, however I couldn't find a way to access the `resizable()` behaviour from the consumers of `RemoteImageView`. Do you know if it has it?

Comment: just use .frame(width:200, height:100)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was removing the whole `AsyncImage` concept. After all, the `ImageDownloader` is likely gonna use some shared global state (e.g. a manager somewhere), so hiding it within `AsyncImage` was not a good choice. Better explicit than implicit :)

Instead, I moved the downloader one level upstream:

```swift
struct UserDetailsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageDownloader: ImageDownloader

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: imageDownloader.image).resizable().aspectRatio(16.0 / 9.0, contentMode: .fit)
            Text(user.name)
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has multiple advantages:

- direct access to all `Image` modifiers
- downloader can be furthermore injected from upstream
- reusability wasn't affected - instead of reusing `AsyncImage`, I reuse `ImageDownloader`

My take from this: trying to make reusable components by mixing business and presentation code is not a good approach. Single Responsibility Principle for the win :)

Answer (score 1):

The approach might be as follows - to proxy required modifiers to internally wrapped `Image`. Not ideal, but in some scenarios worth considering

```
struct AsyncImage: View {
    @ObservedObject private var imageDownloader: ImageDownloader

    private let resizing: Bool

    init(url: URL, resizalbe: Bool = false) {
        imageDownloader = ImageDownloader(url: url)
        resizing = resizalbe
    }

    var body: some View {
        var image = Image(uiImage: imageDownloader.image)
        if resizing {
            image = image.resizable()
        }
        return image
    }

    func resizable() -> Self {
        AsyncImage(url: imageDownloader.url, resizalbe: true)
    }
}
```

as a result the `UserDetailsView` become compilable.

Comment: I considered this, however it doesn't scale very well.