# SwiftUI Error : Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to closure result type 'Void'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, photo, phasset

I get the following SwiftUI error:

```
var assetImage : UIImage? {
        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
            let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
            let assetsFetchResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
            if assetsFetchResults.count > 0 {
                let asset = assetsFetchResults.lastObject
                if asset != nil {
                    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
                    options.version = .current
                    
                    PHCachingImageManager().requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 64 * UIScreen.main.scale, height: 64 * UIScreen.main.scale), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: { img, _ in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            return img //Error Here
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to closure result type 'Void'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of computed property, change it to a method with `completionHandler` as you are accessing the image asynchronously from the `PHCachingImageManager`.

```
func assetImage(_ completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
        let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
        let assetsFetchResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
        if assetsFetchResults.count > 0 {
            let asset = assetsFetchResults.lastObject
            if asset != nil {
                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
                options.version = .current
                
                PHCachingImageManager().requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 64 * UIScreen.main.scale, height: 64 * UIScreen.main.scale), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: { img, _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(img)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
    self.assetImage { (image) in
        
    }
```

Comment: How would I call this in View body?  var body: some View {
        self.assetImage { (image) in
            Image(uiImage: image!)
        }
    } doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Gizmodo Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944208/2395636) to see how you can set an Image.